# How to do this in MySQL: if field value > 0 then minus one, else let it be

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```
UPDATE tbl SET counts=counts-1 ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `count` is the only column you're updating (or, you don't have other criteria specified in your where clause), then you can just do that in the where clause

```
UPDATE [Table] SET counts = counts - 1 WHERE counts > 0;
```

However, if you're updating other columns in the same query, this won't work.  But you have options

```
UPDATE [Table] SET counts = MAX(counts - 1, 0);
```

or

```
UPDATE [Table] SET counts = CASE WHEN counts > 0 THEN counts - 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET counts=counts-1 
WHERE counts > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Peter Bailey

this is the example with the WHERE selector .

```
UPDATE [tbl_multimedia] SET [m_publish] = CASE WHEN [m_publish] = 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END WHERE id='1'
```

Good luck .